# Centering highlight text with box-shadow on a flexbox element

Tags: css, flexbox, highlight, display

I want to center a text with inline display because it need to have a highlight.
Example:
[image: how I want to display the text]

But when this text was in a div with display flex it doesn't work.
The display inline doesn't affect to the text and it can't use flex propierties to center in the div (horizontal o vertical centering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put another div between your highlight text and your `display: flex` div.  Set `text-align: center` on the outmost div.

- No: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpgJxG
- No: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMXEpx
- Yes: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqrzKM